# How to Handle Overlapping Two pop ups in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I came in a situation were When i click on element of a page it displays a popup, and when i click on a element of a current pop up it displays another pop with 'Cancel' and 'delete' button. On first pop up i am able to click without switching, but i am not able to click on 2nd pop up.

Error which I am getting-

> No such Alert

Code I used-

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

and switching frame code also not working.

here is the html-

```
class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
<div class="modal in" id="headingDeletionConfirmationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
    div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="http://ad.ad.co.in/Assessment/deleteCoscholasticHeading" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="heading_Id" value="48" name="heading_Id"> <input type="hidden" id="class_Id" value="7" name="class_Id"> <input type="hidden" id="year_Id" value="20" name="year_id">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure you want to
                        delete this Heading ?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <form action="http://admin.ad.co.in/Assessment/deleteCoscholasticHeading" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="heading_Id" value="48" name="heading_Id"> <input type="hidden" id="class_Id" value="7" name="class_Id"> <input type="hidden" id="year_Id" value="20" name="year_id">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure you want to
                        delete this Heading ?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Any Help?

Comment: It would be helpful to us for understanding the exact problem if your share the relevant HTML of your target site.

Comment: @ShivamMishra updated html

Comment: Are you adding enough wait time before clicking the second pop-up? Share your code snippet for both pop-up actions

Comment: //First pop up
  ViewForm.click();
  DeleteButtons.get(1).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  //second popup
  DeleteClose.click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  DeleteButtons.get(1).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  DeleteYes.click(); 
  Success.isDisplayed();

Comment: @theGuy see above added code